# Sending an iPhone app to to a friend

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am an iPhone developer and I'm trying to figure out how to send an app to the person I built the app for. I have the app finished and such in Xcode. How can I share it with the person? Would I need their iTunes info or, how does it work exactly? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A. If you have had the app running on his iPhone then,
- archive the build, share, send him the ipa file generated. He drags it into iTunes and syncs phone.
B. If he has never had any of you apps on his phone. Get the UDID code from his iPhone
http://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid
Goto http://developer.apple.com/iphone go to the developer provisioning profile and here you can add his device and UDID code.
- Then got back to xCode, open organiser and refresh your certificates to get the new certificate for his device.

Now you can simply archive, share and email ipa file.

Answer (score 3):

If it's for beta testing I can strongly recommend [testflightapp](http://testflightapp.com) where your beta testers can update the app via a link (distributed via email).

Comment: for this do we need to get approve from apple side ?

Answer (score 2):

Look up "Ad Hoc Distribution" in the Developer website.  You will need the other user's UDID for their iOS devices, which they can get from iTunes.  It's all spelled out in the docs.